# Google looker studio - How to blend if a value matches one of 2 columns

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I have 2 tables in Looker Studio. One has a single email address column, the other has 2 email address columns. I want to perform a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.email = table_2.email_1 OR table_1.email = table_2.email_2
```

There doesn't appear to be an obvious way to achieve this in the UI. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can select email address columns as dimensions and choose desired metrics. Then use a cross join to return all possible combinations of rows from both tables.